# Table autofilling formula even with Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False

Tags: excel, vba, office365

Not sure what's going on. I have `Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False` set before assigning a range's formula to an array. The expectation is that the formula's will be uniquely set to a value in the array. Instead, they are immediately auto-filled to the first value in the array.

I've made sure that the array is formatted properly and displays the correct values so long as I don't put "=" in front of the string. Excel only changes the values in the table when the string is a valid Excel formula.

Others in the past have stated that `Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False` should fix this, but I'm thinking Office365 is different. As a side note, Excel is also adding rows automatically to the table even with that option turned off (although I do want that to happen). Maybe macros have different settings than excel itself? Any suggestions?

Edit: Adding some example code which produces the same result for me.

```
Public Sub Test()
    
    Dim testTable As ListObject
    
    If Sheet1.ListObjects.Count = 0 Then
        Set testTable = Sheet1.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1), Sheet1.Cells(3, 1)))
    Else
        Set testTable = Sheet1.ListObjects(1)
    End If
        
    Dim dataArray As Variant
    dataArray = Application.Transpose(Array("=""Formula 1""", "=""Formula 2""", "=""Formula 3"""))
        
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False
    testTable.DataBodyRange.Formula = dataArray
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Sure @BigBen, just added a block. This produces the same result. Removing the "=" will set each cell to the expected unique values but with the "=" Excel seems to autofill the formula as copies instead.

Comment: Yeah, I'm stumped as well. Maybe a workaround would be to set them individually using a loop, but my actual project is a doc with thousands of cells. Setting them using an array is near instant, but individually would take forever so this is not feasible.

Comment: Can you convert to a range (unmake it a table), write the formulas, and then convert back to table? The problem with this approach would be if your formulas use structured references.

Comment: Hmmm, it does in the sample and thankfully my table formula will not be using references. I'll have to test on the actual doc which will take a bit. If it works that's great for this project at least. Hopefully I either don't have a use case for other circumstances or there is another solution.

Comment: Interestingly enough `.FormulaArray` can write the original formulas in, but they're array formulas... you probably don't want braces appearing around them.

Comment: Seems like you can also write in "chunks" - as long as you don't write to the entire column, `.Formula` works.

Comment: So that works in the example, but for some reason that adds a Totals Row to the table's second row which messes up all the rest of the entries in my project doc. I'm thinking it's because I'm setting the entire table at the same time while only passing in one Formula.

Yup, okay so what I did was set the entire table with the array and then rewrite the single column with data afterwards using it's .FormulaArray and it worked! Hoping there aren't any issues with it being an array formula but it seems fine for the moment at least for my purposes. Thanks for working through this with me @BigBen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I'm not sure this was possible even before Excel 365, and would welcome proof to the contrary (I can no longer test).

Several options, each of which might have issues:

- Convert the table to a range (unmake it a table), write the formulas, and reconvert. This won't work if your formulas include structured references.
- Use `.FormulaArray`, if your formulas don't break as array formulas and you don't mind the enclosing `{}` in the formula bar.
- Use `.Formula` but write the formulas in "chunks" - i.e. split your array into several smaller arrays and write them in succession.

Comment: On the last bullet - what defines a "chunk"? How do I know how to split the array?

Comment: @Fredrik - probably depending on what values the array contains. With the originally posted data, I guess three arrays. That bullet was somewhat theoretical tho, and I never could test it.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness I'll update the sample code with the FormulaArray workaround. The following works for a single column:

```
Public Sub Test()
    
    Dim testTable As ListObject
    
    If Sheet1.ListObjects.Count = 0 Then
        Set testTable = Sheet1.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1), Sheet1.Cells(3, 1)))
    Else
        Set testTable = Sheet1.ListObjects(1)
    End If
        
    Dim dataArray As Variant
    dataArray = Application.Transpose(Array("=""Formula 1""", "=""Formula 2""", "=""Formula 3"""))
    
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False
    testTable.DataBodyRange.FormulaArray = dataArray
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = True
    
End Sub
```

If you have a table with multiple columns though:

```
Public Sub Test()
        
    Dim testTable As ListObject
    
    If Sheet1.ListObjects.Count = 0 Then
        Set testTable = Sheet1.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1), Sheet1.Cells(3, 2)))
    Else
        Set testTable = Sheet1.ListObjects(1)
    End If
    
    Dim newFormulaArray As Variant
    newFormulaArray = Array("=""Formula 1""", "=""Formula 2""", "=""Formula 3""")
    
    Dim newDataArray As Variant
    newDataArray = Array("Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3")
    
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False

    testTable.DataBodyRange.Value = Application.Transpose(Array(newFormulaArray, newDataArray))
    
    testTable.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.FormulaArray = Application.Transpose(newFormulaArray)

    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = True
        
End Sub
```